# Foreign key join on 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, inner-join, primary-key

I have a table TableA that holds 2 different foreign keys of tables TableB and TableC. I'm trying to get the data from table TableB but depending on value from table TableC.

With this query I get all the values but I don't know how to write where clause to filter and get data that I need.

```
SELECT TableC.value1,TableB.value2 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID 
JOIN TableC ON TableC.ID = TableA.ID
```

Edit : 
Picture of my tables.
[image]

So I'm trying to show data from table B, but only those that match in table C.

New edit : 
[image]

I get the values from 2 tables,but now I need to show only column A value that is equal to "val2". Image that column B have values as "val2" "val2" "val3" and so on. I need to show only that which is "val2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `WHERE` clause. What you need is fix your `JOIN` and make it `JOIN` the `tablec` with the condition `TableA.TableC_ID = TableC.ID` instead, like this:

```
SELECT TableC.value1,TableB.value2 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID        = TableA.ID 
JOIN TableC ON TableA.TableC_ID = TableC.ID
WHERE tableA.ColumnA = 'val2';
```

Comment: @user3759362 - Then add that to the `where` clause like this: `    WHERE tableA.ColumnA = 'val2';`

Comment: And I get zero results.

Comment: @user3759362 - Can you please paste sample data from all the three tables `tableA`, `tableB`, and `tableC` and the desired results you are lookin for? please edit your question and add these details so that I understand what you are looking for.'

Comment: Table A holds only foreign keys and own table primary key. TableB have columns ("ID","City"), city is string. TableC have columns ("ID","Type") Consider that column type has value "room","other" and it is also string. My goal is to show city that has a type for example "room".

Comment: @user3759362 - Try this `SELECT TableB.City
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID        = TableA.ID 
JOIN TableC ON TableA.TableC_ID = TableC.ID
WHERE tableC.Type = 'room';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67471/discussion-between-user3759362-and-mahmoud-gamal).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
SELECT TableC.value1,TableB.value2 
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID 
JOIN TableC ON TableC.ID = TableA.ID 
WHERE TableC.myColumn = MyValue
```

Comment: I was doing the same way,but my result was empty. Give me a sec I'll draw a tables in paint to show what exactly I have.

Comment: hmm.. with value do you want to filter? string, int... ? maybe your where statemante is wrong... check with (SELECT * FROM TableC WHERE myColumn = myValue)